# Is there any way to define two states inside Axios .catch method?

Tags: reactjs, post, react-hooks, axios, mern

Iam trying to update two states inside axios.post method but while trying to login by clicking login button the page goes blank and when i comment or delete one of the state i.e  setEmptyFields(error.response.data.emptyFields) or  setError(error.response.data.message) it works but while using both it doesnot is there  any way to handle this issue ??

```
const response = await axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/login", loginUser)
      .catch((error) =>
        setEmptyFields(error.response.data.emptyFields)
        setError(error.response.data.message)
      );
```

Comment: usually you would only use one state. the error messages in the console tell you where exactly it goes wrong. setting 2 states would also work. i always set loading and error in my .catch so im 100% sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `await` keyword, use a `try/catch`.

```js
try {
  const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/login", loginUser)
  //do something with the response...
} catch(error) {
  setEmptyFields(error.response.data.emptyFields)
  setError(error.response.data.message)
}
```

Alternatively you can use `then` to handle the response:

```js
axios
  .post("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/login", loginUser)
  .then((response) => {
    //do something with the response...
  })
  .catch((error) =>
    setEmptyFields(error.response.data.emptyFields)
    setError(error.response.data.message)
  );
```